# datetime is chaning date and month wrongly for some cases

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to change a `object` to a `datetime` value.

```
 id        date
  1  07/03/2020
  2  20/02/2020
```

In the above `df` the column `date` is in the format `%d%m%Y` in strings value and when I apply `df['date'] = pd.datetime(df['date'])` i have the following results:

```
 id        date
  1  2020-07-03
  2  2020-02-20
```

and the format of this new datetime column is on `%Y%m%d`. It is very strange that the first value `df` has change the day for the month and the month for the day meanwhile in the second row has converted correctly mantaining the values for day and month.

Comment: pd.datetime(df['date'],dayfirst=True)

Comment: It's not 'wrong'. one of your inputs is ambiguous and the other is not as there are only 12 months in the year. So `20/02/2020` has to parse to 20th February whereas `07/03/2020` could be July 3rd or 7th March. The default for dayfirst is false - see https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html so it is parsed as July 3rd.

Answer (score 2):

You should try specifying the format when you convert:

```py
import pandas as pd

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```